# SQL Lag function and where clause

Tags: sql, lag

I'm new in SQL and I want to write a query where we keep the rows where, for the same item:

- column1_value is NULL AND
- the previous not null column1_value is 'end' OR
- the previous column1_value is NULL

Everything else is discarted.

I know I have to use LAG function i've not been able to reach to a final query. Can you help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @Shabbir, please add the variant of SQL (ie: oracle, MySQL, postgres etc;)

Comment: Helloo @thusith.92, i'm using sql in pyspark (idk if it helps)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(column1) over (order by ordercol) as prev_column1
      from t
     ) t
where column1 is null and 
      (prev_column1 = 'end' or prev_column1 is null)
```